# List of files (which might contain wildcards) as arguments of a Python script

Tags: python, glob

In many python scripts I find my self doing the following:

```
for maybe_glob in sys.argv[1:]:
    for filename in glob.iglob(maybe_glob):
        print(filename)
```

I have to do this because the scripts need to also run in terminals that do not expand wildcards (such as windows). Is there shorter version for this? Is there a way (for example with argparser) to directly expand wildcards during argument parsing?

Thanks

Comment: I see nothing wrong with the code you have posted (except that you're using argv directly instead of through a library, which can be messy).

Comment: I would be careful with anything like this.  `*` is a valid character in unix/linux/posix filenames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could avoid the double loop with a chaining iterator, but it hardly seems like an improvement.

```
for fname in itertools.chain(*map(glob.iglob, sys.argv[1:])):
    print fname
```

But you could wrap it into a routine:

```
def allglob(args):
    return itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(glob.iglob, args))
```